# CentOS 7 - Correctly add local package to yum repository

Tags: centos, package, rpm, yum

I'm trying to add a local RPM package to `yum` and yet install it. 
To add it to `yum` repository I run: `yum-config-manager --add-repo file:///path/to/local/package.rpm` and then `yum install package` to install it. However, I got this output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de
 * epel: mirror.23media.de
 * extras: centos.mirrors.psw.services
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
harbottle.gitlab.io_harbottle-main_7_x86_64_                                                          | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
file:///path/to/local/package.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /path/to/local/package.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (added from: file:/path/to/local/package.x86_64.rpm),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=path_to_local_package.x86_64.rpm ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable path_to_local_package.x86_64.rpm
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=path_to_local_package.x86_64.rpm

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=path_to_local_package.x86_64.rpm.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from path_to_local_package.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
file:/path/to/local/package.x86_64.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /path/to/local/package.rpm/repodata/repomd.xml"
```

I also tried to first run: `yum-config-manager --add-repo file:///path/to/local/package.rpm` and then `createrepo --database /path/to/local/` but I got the same output.

Does anybody know how to correctly add a local RPM package to the `yum` repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a **repository** is different from a **rpm package**. A repository is a directory containing multiple rpms. So if you just want to install your rpm; you can just

```
yum install /path/to/package.rpm
```

if you want to start hosting your own **repository**; then you need to look into `createrepo`. For example a local directory can be turned into a repository like this:

```
mkdir /myrepo
cp package.rpm /myrepo
cd /myrepo
createrepo .
```

now you can add this directory to `yum`:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo file:///myrepo
```

now you can also keep adding rpms to this directory (don't forget to run `createrepo` each time).

Comment: Thanks for your help in my turbulent journey through RPM and yum @chrismae :) I tried the second part of your answer but I got as output this (when I finally run: `yum install tomcat8`): `Public key for tomcat8-8.5.37-2.el7.harbottle.x86_64.rpm is not installed
[root@dblab-dev-03 RPMS]# service tomcat8 status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status tomcat8.service
Unit tomcat8.service could not be found.
`. As you can observe when I run `service tomcat8` there is no service found.

Comment: then you need to check if the tomcat8.service file is installed by your package: `rpm -ql tomcat8 | grep service` or something like that. Suppose the file did get installed; try running `systemctl daemon-reload` before running `systemctl start tomcat8`

Comment: Actually, the installation was not completed; hence the missing tomcat8.service file. The process was interrupted because there was no gpg key. I ran `yum install --nogpgcheck tomcat8` and it worked correctly.